# Disable Babel cache in babel.config.json file for development purposes?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I'm using `babel-node` to transpile on the fly for my development. Babel however does not pickup my changes to JS files loading older versions of the file, to say the least it is quite irritating. I'm guessing caching is the culprit here.

I can't however find a simple property to set in the `babel.config.json` to disable this, or how is one supposed to setup Babel for dev purposes!

My config:

```
{
    "presets": [["@babel/preset-env", { "targets": { "node": "current" } }]],
    "plugins": []
}
```

Comment: What does your current `babel.config.json` look like?

Comment: @AKX just added!

Comment: Hm, I didn't think it'd cache things unless explicitly told to... Well, there are some somewhat related hacks and such for this over at https://github.com/kentcdodds/babel-plugin-preval/issues/19